# Angular & Django Rest Framework

Tags: angularjs, django, django-rest-framework

I have an API powered by Django rest framework and I also use the default pagination option:

```
{
    "count": 40, 
    "next": "http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/task/?page=2", 
    "previous": null, 
    "results": [{},{}...]
}
```

On angular side, I'm using ngResource to consume my api wiht the following code:

```
var task_resource = $resource('/api/task/:taskId/', {taskId:'@id'},{
  query : {
    method : 'GET',
    isArray : false
  }
});
```

I just want to be able, when the user click a 'next' button or scroll down to the bottom of the page to query the 'next' page until the end. I know I only have to GET on "next" field but if I do that, I will not use the $resource I defined.

I am wondering what is the solution for such a common pattern with angular and an API.

Answer (score 0):

Since the 'next' url is absolute, you could simply use angular's built-in $http service for those requests. Something like `$http.get(data.next).success(function(data){});`

Another way would be to create your own custom pagination serializer as described here: http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/pagination#custom-pagination-serializers

Then you would need to create your own version of the `NextPageField`, and make it output without the domain part.

The standard implementation for the NextPageField can be found here:
https://github.com/tomchristie/django-rest-framework/blob/560f428e24c7676c660114c2daa6017ff61074ad/rest_framework/pagination.py